# Used github's undo pull request feature, now cannot update from upstream without undoing work

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project right now where I make my changes on a fork of the main repository. Recently, I made a mistake, and somehow merged a pull request on the main repository that I shouldn't have. I used the undo pull request feature from Github, but this just simply created another pull request that deleted all the changes my original pull request made. Because of this, I can no longer update my fork from the upstream main repository, as that will undo all the changes that I have made.

I've attempted to update from upstream on my fork on Github. As I feared, when looking at the changes, all of my work gets reverted by the pull request from the master repository. I haven't tried too many other things yet out of fear. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Updating from the upstream is the correct thing to do. What you need to do after that is to "revert the revert" in your local fork; this will add back your changes locally. I would recommend creating a new branch for this - for example, if the reverted branch is named `my_feature`, and the hash of the commit that undid your changes was `#abc123`, do:

```
git checkout -b my_feature_attempt_2
git revert #abc123 -m "re-adding changes from my_feature"
```

You can then modify the files in `my_feature_attempt_2` and resubmit your PR (if desired).